# MobileInstallationInstall progress

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I wanna install a ipa on a jailbreak i-device.I get this code bellow on google. Here is the code

```
#import "dlfcn.h"


typedef int (*MobileInstallationInstall)(NSString *path, NSDictionary *dict, void *na, NSString *path2_equal_path_maybe_no_use);


    void *lib = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation", RTLD_LOCAL);
    if (lib)
    {
        MobileInstallationInstall pMobileInstallationInstall = (MobileInstallationInstall)dlsym(lib, "MobileInstallationInstall");
        if (pMobileInstallationInstall)
        {
            int ret = pMobileInstallationInstall(path, [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"User" forKey:@"ApplicationType"], nil, path);
            dlclose(lib);

            return ret;
        }
    }
    return -1;
```

But that's not enough.I wanna get the install progress.Just like download progress. Unfortunately,I get nothing on google.any ideas?

Comment: ;( ;( ;( ;( ;( ;( ;(

Comment: MobileInstallation framework is probably deprecated as many functions were removed from it. You may wanna look at this https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/LSApplicationWorkspace.h That's what modern iOS versions use

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify a callback function on the third parameter of **MobileInstallationInstall**

```
void MobileInstallationCallback(CFDictionaryRef information){
    NSLog(@"%@",information);
}

int ret = pMobileInstallationInstall(path, [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"User" forKey:@"ApplicationType"], & MobileInstallationCallback, path);
```

all the informations will be sent to MobileInstallationCallback via the parameter information